# .Net Core Microsoft.Web.Administration ServerManager from Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, servermanager

.net core version: 2.1.500

OS: Debian 9 (4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
)

I am trying to stop/start application pool from Linux OS via ServerManager but no success.
According api catalog it should works:
https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager

ServerManager.OpenRemote() throw NullReference exception when trying to ApplicationPools:

```
// also trying ip adress
using (ServerManager manager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("someserver"))
{
    try
    {
        if (manager.ApplicationPools == null) /* <= Here is exception!!! */
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ApplicationPool is null!");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in manager.ApplicationPools)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  " + item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(" Trace=" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Result:

> Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Trace=   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateWritableAdminManager(WebConfigurationMap
>   webConfigMap, String configPathToEdit, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean
>   isRedirectionConfig)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateConfiguration(WebConfigurationMap
>   configMap, String configPathToEdit, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean
>   isRedirectionConfig)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration(String
>   rawConfigurationPath, String cacheKey, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean
>   isRedirectionConfig)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolsSectionCreator()
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolCollectionCreator()
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory)
>       at SomeMethod() in some_file.cs:line 123

When ServerManager creates via constructor that take string ApplicationPools throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException exception:

```
using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager(@"\\someserver\IISSharedConfig\applicationHost.config"))
{
    try
    {
        if (manager.ApplicationPools == null) /* <= Here is exception!!! */
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ApplicationPool is null!");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in manager.ApplicationPools)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  " + item.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        Exception e = ex.InnerException;
        while (e != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("InnerException: " + e.Message);
            e = e.InnerException;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" Trace=" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Result:

> Exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
>   InnerException: COM is not supported   Trace=   at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
>       at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
>       at System.Activator.CreateInstanceT
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateAdminManager[TClass,TInterface](WebConfigurationMap
>   webConfigMap, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean isRedirectionConfig)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateWritableAdminManager(WebConfigurationMap
>   webConfigMap, String configPathToEdit, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean
>   isRedirectionConfig)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CreateConfiguration(WebConfigurationMap
>   configMap, String configPathToEdit, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean
>   isRedirectionConfig)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.GetConfiguration(String
>   rawConfigurationPath, String cacheKey, Boolean isAdminConfig, Boolean
>   isRedirectionConfig)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolsSectionCreator()
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory)
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.ApplicationPoolCollectionCreator()
>       at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Lazy.Initialize[T](T& target, CreateInstanceDelegate`1 valueFactory)
>       at SomeMethod() in some_file.cs:line 123

How to use ServerManager in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do isn't supported on **Linux**. See at the bottom of the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.applicationpools(v=vs.90).aspx) you posted in your question:

> **Platform**
>
> .NET Standard + Platform Extensions

As far as I remember, the **Platform Extensions** are additions that are not cross platform, thus cannot be used in an application running on **Linux**.

You can also see a hint to that in the second error you posted:

> COM is not supported

Which is true on **Linux**.

Hope it helps!